# Pig unable to find input folder/files

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I created my files locally, copied them to pig input folder by `hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal` command. I can see the files in my specified folder by h`dfs dfs -ls`, but when I run my script by `pig -x local`, it cannot find the input folder. `"ERROR 2118: Input Pattern file:/user/cloudera/pigin/testfile*` matches 0 files". I am running on mac os x.

Comment: You are running pig in local mode, so why did you bother putting files in HDFS? Also,  of course `/user/cloudera` isn't a path on the Mac

Comment: You are right it worked after I used input files as a local folder

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are running your pig in local mode and ur files are present in HDFS. Try Pig -x mapred ot pig

Answer (score 0):

Your files are copied in HDFS, while you are running your script in local   execution mode. In that case, it will look for files in local file system.

To access HDFS file, execution mode should be map-reduce. So run pigscript in following way :

```
/* mapreduce mode */
$ pig <pigscript.pig>
or
$ pig -x mapreduce <pigscript.pig>
```